# _MigrationHistory not detected even though it exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

The following used to work. I am unsure what has changed.

```
var db = new MyDbContext()
var compatible = db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)
```

gives the following error

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
> contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for
> databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

I have been able to create and run the migrations using Package Manager and I can see the code in the Migrations folder.

I can see the migrations in the __MigrationHistory table.

I resolved the issue in a different database when the user did not have access to the table. However in this case the user does have access.

The table shows the product version is 6.4.4

[image: help message]

I tried creating a new migration to see if there were any differences, but it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the configuration.cs in the migrations folder

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MigrationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
```

}

Then I corrected the type

```
var db = new MigrationDbContext()
```

Then I changed the